# How to find from a pandas DataFrame the three closest values?

Tags: python, pandas, euclidean-distance

I have a dataframe which contain different emotion, every emotion is a category and has three different float values. I would like to find the closest emotion giving three values.

---

**Example:**

```py
df_emotional = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category'  : ['anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'guilt', 'joy', 'negative', 'positive', 'sadness', 'shame'],
    'n1'        : [0.167, 0.052, 0.073, 0.208, 0.980, 0.102, 0.959, 0.052, 0.060],
    'n2'        : [0.865, 0.775, 0.840, 0.567, 0.824, 0.527, 0.510, 0.288, 0.670],
    'n3'        : [0.657, 0.317, 0.293, 0.206, 0.794, 0.176, 0.855, 0.164, 0.155]
})

def closest_values(df, n1, n2, n3):
   n1_res = min(df, key=lambda x: abs(x - n1))
   ...
   return emotion

# Expected output
closest_values(df_emotional, n1=0.161, n2=0.991, n3=0.632)
output: anger
```

Comment: You can use KNN Machine Learning Method for that.

Comment: @Inputvector you are right, I will try it :)

Comment: I implemented for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution implemented by KNN method. Note that I didn't apply any machine learning best practices like test and training split etc. If you have bigger dataset you can implement. Basically Knn calculate euclidean_distance between the rows and pick nearest one (you can increase this value) to decide the category.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

df_emotional = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category'  : ['anger', 'disgust', 'fear', 'guilt', 'joy', 'negative', 'positive', 'sadness', 'shame'],
    'n1'        : [0.167, 0.052, 0.073, 0.208, 0.980, 0.102, 0.959, 0.052, 0.060],
    'n2'        : [0.865, 0.775, 0.840, 0.567, 0.824, 0.527, 0.510, 0.288, 0.670],
    'n3'        : [0.657, 0.317, 0.293, 0.206, 0.794, 0.176, 0.855, 0.164, 0.155]
    
})

X = df_emotional.iloc[:, 1:]
y = df_emotional.iloc[:, 0]


clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1) #nearest 1 neighbor.
clf.fit(X,y)

clf.predict([[0.161, 0.991, 0.632]])

#Output:

array(['anger'], dtype=object)
```

Note: You can save your clf method for future predictions for more information : [Model Persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)